# Weird behaviour of a C program

Tags: c

I have been using windows all this time and recently installed Ubuntu on Virtual Box. To give Ubuntu a try,i wrote a simple calculator program.

Here's how it goes:

```
#include<stdio.h>
float add(float ,float ),sub(float , float ),mul(float ,float ),div(float ,float );
int main()
{
char ch;
float a,b;
printf("Enter an operator: ");
scanf("%c",&ch);
printf("Enter two values: ");
scanf("%f%f",&a,&b);
switch(ch)
{
    case '+':
        printf("The sum of %f and %f is %f\n",a,b,add(a,b));
        break;
    case '-':
        printf("The substraction of %f from %f is %f\n",a,b,sub(a,b));
        break;
    case '*':
        printf("The multiplication of %f and %f is %f\n",a,b,mul(a,b));
        break;
    case '/':
        printf("The division of %f and %f is %f\n",a,b,div(a,b));
        break;
    default:
        printf("\nEnter a valid operator: \n");
        main();
}
return 1;
}
float add(float x,float y)
{
    return (float)x + y;
}
float sub(float x,float y)
{
    return (float)x-y;
}
float mul(float x,float y)
{
    return (float) x*y;
}
float div(float x,float y)
{
    return (float) x/y;
}
```

when i enter an invalid operator,it should actually read the operator and values again. But, it's asking for values directly without reading the operator. Here's a picture:

[image: Running the code]

So what am i doing wrong? please explain. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You **never** call `main()` yourself directly. You're wanting to loop, not restart your entire application. Find a C tutorial.

Comment: The lines of a C program execute in the order that you write them, unless there's a jump of some sort.  So if you look at your own code, what happens right after you read the operator?  That's not the only thing wrong with your program; there are several other problems.

Comment: @Robert but when i enter an invalid operator, it doesnt read operator again?

Comment: `float main()` is totally non-standard.  See [What should `main()` return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c/) for the gory details.

Comment: Calling `main()` is legal in C, it's just another function. He can do this and it will work until his stack overflows (or work forever if the compiler knows about tail recursion).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not ignore the newlines in your inputs.

Change

```
scanf("%c", &ch);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c", &ch);
```

and try again.

When you input `3<enter>`, that `3` will be consumed by the second `%f`, but that `<enter>` (i.e. newline) will still in the input buffer, and the `%c` in the first `scanf()` will consume this newline. The space in `%c` will ignore that newline in the input buffer.

---

```
$ ./a.out
Enter an operator: h
Enter two values: 2
3

Enter a valid operator: 
Enter an operator: +
Enter two values: 2
3
The sum of 2.000000 and 3.000000 is 5.000000
```

Comment: tried the edit too. The cursor keeps blinking and didnt read the operator second time :/

Comment: @PruthviRaj It works for me. Are you sure you include all those spaces in the format strings?

Comment: Yeah! my bad sorry, why didnt it work earlier(i mean before making those changes) , can you please explain?

Comment: The only conversion specifiers that do not ignore leading white space are `%c`, `%n` and `%[…]` (scan sets).  All the others, including `%f` specifically, automatically ignore leading white space, so the change to `"%f%f"` is not necessary.